Getting `No module named 'google.auth.api_key'` in Python Anywhere
I got an error while creating a Flask API. It says:
File "/home/vishal6596/mysite/flask_app.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gspread
  File "/home/vishal6596/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gspread/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .auth import (
  File "/home/vishal6596/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gspread/auth.py", line 14, in <module>
    from google.auth.api_key import Credentials as APIKeyCredentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth.api_key'

I thought about using gspread to write data to Google Sheet using Flask api but the gspread library is not working in Python Anywhere.
When I tried the same code in pycharm it worked well and gave me the desired output. What can I try next?

Do you have environment variables that pycharm is setting so that your api key is available?

What version of the google-auth package are you using?

How is gspread not working on PythonAnywhere?  The error you pasted is about a missing package -- make sure you are running your code on PA in the environment with google.auth.api_key available.

Thanks I just created a new vir env and then added the libraries in it now it works fine

I have the same problem when running inside python 3.11 environment but it does work inside python 3.6 environment.
I found pinning gspread to gspread==5.9.0 worked for me.
